# Issue with array acces in lua

Tags: string, split, lua, lua-table, data-manipulation

I am not sure why this does not work:

```
-- split data into an array of chars
dataList = string.gmatch(data, ".")

-- edit char 5 DOES NOT WORK
dataList[5] = 0x66

-- Print out the data in hex
for chr in dataList do
  io.write(string.format("[%02x] ", string.byte(chr)))
end
```

So if I remove the line dataList[5] = 0x66 then this works ok. So I don't get why I can't modify the element 5. The error I get is even more confusing for me:

```
Error: main.lua:33: attempt to index global 'dataList' (a function value)
stack traceback:
        main.lua:33: in function 'update'
        [string "boot.lua"]:463: in function <[string "boot.lua"]:435>
        [C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

What does that mean? - how can I achieve this?

Really all I want to do is modify a specific character of a string - but in lua people are saying you can't do it because they are immutable. So my idea is to split the string into an array and then modify this and then turn it back into a string when I am done...

**update**

Thanks to hjpotter92 I now have:

```
dataList = {data:byte(1, data:len())}         
dataList[5] = 0x66    
if dataList then
  finalString = string.char(table.unpack(dataList))     -- <---- this does not work :(
  printStringAsHex("final", finalString)  
end
```

However I am struggling to turn this back into a string, I get the error:

> Error: main.lua:34: attempt to call field 'unpack' (a nil value) stack
>   traceback:
>           main.lua:34: in function 'update'
>           [string "boot.lua"]:463: in function <[string "boot.lua"]:435>
>           [C]: in function 'xpcall'

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/string/gmatch.html) for `string.gmatch`, particularly the part about what it returns?

Comment: @user2357112 ah, ok I did look at the docs, but I missed the return type.... how the heck do I achieve what I want to do then? - I have been staring at endless examples, can't see how; I don't want to do some complex string substitution thing (I have see people doing that... I miss simple C-style char arrays : (

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to perhaps store the string as a table (arrays are actually `table`s in lua):

```
dataList = {data:byte(1, data:len())}
dataList[5] = 0x66

print( string.char(table.unpack(dataList)) )
```

**update**

Didn't want to write a separate answer, so I have added a complete working example for any Lua version based on all the great answers / feedback. This is just for reference in case someone else encounters similar issues...

```
unpack = unpack or table.unpack

data = string.char(0x42, 0x42, 0x43, 0x15, 0x034, 0x33, 0x48)
dataList = {data:byte(1, data:len())}
dataList[5] = 0x66
print(string.char(unpack(dataList)))
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it seems to make sense... only I get an error when I change to this: `Error: main.lua:30: attempt to call upvalue 'data' (a string value)`. The error is for the first line. I will try this as a standalone bit of code. I am getting `data` as a return value from a udp packet, I am assume it is a string - it says it is....

Comment: @code_fodder damn!  that was supposed to be `data:byte()`. Fixed now!

Comment: Oh yes, that worked now :)) ... I don't suppose you can show me how to put the table back into a string (e.g. once I have finished editing the contents)...   I can't tell if I need to use concat, or unpack() - I had a few goes with unpack but I think it produces a list/table? ...

Comment: @code_fodder `table.concat` would've worked, but since we're storing the ascii values of all the characters, we need to convert them back to characters first. This is achieved by combining `string.char` and `table.unpack` together.

Comment: (sorry for slow reply, had to go home) So, I tried that, but I get an error. I added an update to my original question to show details (because I can't add them here - too small). I think the `string.char(table.unpack(dataList))` does not work, but I can't see why... thanks for your help :)

Comment: mmmm... infact I am using love for this code, I tried it in lua and it works. I don't understand why love does not work - it uses lua 5.1... I am looking into it, I might have to raise this as a different question though (unless you have any further thoughts?)

Comment: In Lua 5.1 use plain `unpack(dataList)` instead of `table.unpack(dataList)` (the `unpack` function moved into the `table` module in Lua 5.2).

Comment: @code_fodder what siffiejoe said above ^. Love's engine is still probably on Lua 5.1.

Comment: @siffiejoe & hjpotter  .....oohhh, I see! - I was just tapping out a really long winded question, basically asking why all my various lua's behave differently! - I even have one called LuaJIT :o. So that clears that up :) ... but if you want your code to work on both versions (e.g. `if lua51 then .... else if >=lua52 then ... end`), can you do that?

Comment: @code_fodder You can also put a `local unpack = unpack or table.unpack` somewhere, and later, use `unpack(dataList)`

Comment: That's a good idea (I did not know you could do that!) ... but how do you determine what version of lua you are using in code?

Comment: Just updated your post with the complete example for other peoples ref...hope u dont mind!

Comment: @code_fodder No problem. I've modified that further to reduce unnecessary checks etc.

Comment: ahhhh... I didn't think what you wrote in your comment was actual working code, i.e. `local unpack = unpack or table.unpack` I thought that was pseudo code, that's cool!